# How to add, edit, delete and save xml node in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

My xml file is like this,

```
<GALLERY COLUMNS="3" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
<IMAGE FULL="Tinku.png" Title="Tinku" THUMB="thumbs/thumb1.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Tinku" />
<IMAGE FULL="Kaal.png" Title="Kaal" THUMB="thumbs/thumb2.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Kaal" />
<IMAGE FULL="Painters.png" Title="Little Painters" THUMB="thumbs/thumb3.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Painters" />
</GALLERY>
```

How to add a new node like the one below,

```
<IMAGE FULL="Lost.png" Title="Lost and Found" THUMB="thumbs/thumb4.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Lost" />
```

Also i want to know how to delete a particular node

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("gallery.xml"));
            myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

        function processXML(e:Event):void {
            myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
            images = myXML.IMAGE;
            total = images.length();
            myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
            myXMLLoader = null;             
            var imageName:String = images[i].@FULL;
            loader = new Loader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + imageName));
        }

add_bt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addnode);
private function addnode(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var new_node:XML = <IMAGE FULL="Lost.png" Title="Lost and Found" THUMB="thumbs/thumb4.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Lost" />
            myXML.appendChild(new_node);
            trace(myXML);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an XML node to your [`XML`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) object, you can use [`XML.appendChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#appendChild()) like this :

```
var xml:XML = 
<GALLERY COLUMNS="3" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
    <IMAGE FULL="Tinku.png" Title="Tinku" THUMB="thumbs/thumb1.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Tinku" />
    <IMAGE FULL="Kaal.png" Title="Kaal" THUMB="thumbs/thumb2.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Kaal" />
    <IMAGE FULL="Painters.png" Title="Little Painters" THUMB="thumbs/thumb3.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Painters" />
</GALLERY>;

var new_node:XML = <IMAGE FULL="Lost.png" Title="Lost and Found" THUMB="thumbs/thumb4.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Lost" />
xml.appendChild(new_node);

trace(xml);
```

gives :

```
<GALLERY COLUMNS="3" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
    <IMAGE FULL="Tinku.png" Title="Tinku" THUMB="thumbs/thumb1.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Tinku"/>
    <IMAGE FULL="Kaal.png" Title="Kaal" THUMB="thumbs/thumb2.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Kaal"/>
    <IMAGE FULL="Painters.png" Title="Little Painters" THUMB="thumbs/thumb3.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Painters"/>
    <IMAGE FULL="Lost.png" Title="Lost and Found" THUMB="thumbs/thumb4.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Lost"/>
</GALLERY>
```

Then, to delete an XML node, you can use the [`delete()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#delete) operator :

```
// delete the node with the "Title" attribut is 'Kaal'
delete xml.*.(@Title == 'Kaal')[0];

trace(xml);
```

gives :

```
<GALLERY COLUMNS="3" XPOSITION="30" YPOSITION="30" WIDTH="150" HEIGHT="150">
    <IMAGE FULL="Tinku.png" Title="Tinku" THUMB="thumbs/thumb1.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Tinku"/>
    <IMAGE FULL="Painters.png" Title="Little Painters" THUMB="thumbs/thumb3.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Painters"/>
    <IMAGE FULL="Lost.png" Title="Lost and Found" THUMB="thumbs/thumb4.jpg" Path="file:///storage/emulated/0/Raconteur/Lost"/>
</GALLERY>
```

For more details about working with XML you can take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still the xml file was not saved with the appended node.

Comment: @SankarR This code is just to edit the xml content not to save it ! Could you show your code ?

Comment: @SankarR But in your code there is nothing about saving the xml ?! And is that for AIR or Flash ?

Comment: @SankarR I all cases, take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31057995/2256820) there you can find how to save a file for AIR or Flash.