# Save data to PersistanceManager or SharedObject

Tags: flash, actionscript, local-shared-object, persistence-manager

```
import spark.managers.PersistenceManager;


var persistenceManager: PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();
persistenceManager.setProperty('Story1', counter_stories);
persistenceManager.save();
```

Error message: Can not find spark.managers:PersistenceManager.

I like to save data in adobe flash action script for mobile app in this way. It contains several counters and numbers.

Maybe using a local Shared Object is a better way to do this?

Comment: Which Flex SDK version are you using because the [`PersistenceManager`](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/managers/PersistenceManager.html) class is available from Flex 4.5 ? For the shared objects, you can use it to read and store limited amounts of data, so if it's your case, it will be the best choice, otherwise, you can use a file ( text file, SQLite db, ... ) to save your data. For more details, take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31057995/2256820).

Comment: I am using Adobe Flash CC 2015/AIR17.0. Instead of using the PersistanceManager I tried the same example with using a SharedObject and I manage to store a value that way and to retrieve it. So I think that is the way to go. Need to test it on the iPad still.